# State is undefined in mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, action, state, reducers

I've been trying to retrieve the new state from my vitaminReducer() reducer function, and connect it through mapStateToProps. But when I console.log the state, I get back "the state is {vitamin: undefined}".

This is the Vitamins component where I'm calling mapStateToProps()
(Vitamins.js)

```
  componentDidMount() {
     this.props.fetchVitamins();
   }

  function mapStateToProps(state) {
     return {
      vitamin: state,
     }
  };

  console.log('the state is', mapStateToProps());

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchVitamins })(Vitamins);
```

(reducers.js)

```
 function vitaminReducer(state = [], action) {
   switch(action.type) {
    case FETCH_VITAMINS_SUCCESS:
      return [
        ...state,
        action.payload.vitamins
      ];
     default:
       return state;
    }
  }


  const reducers = combineReducers({
    vitamin: vitaminReducer,
  });
```

I have the data coming through an Express server. I've console logged "vitamins" here and I get the data back, so I know that's not the issue.

(actions.js)

```
 export function fetchVitamins() {
   return dispatch => {
     return fetch("/users")
       .then(handleErrors)
       .then(res => res.json())
       .then(micros => {
          dispatch(fetchVitaminsSuccess(micros));
          const vitamins = micros.vitamins;
        }
     )};
  };

  export const FETCH_VITAMINS_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_VITAMINS_SUCCESS';

  export const fetchVitaminsSuccess = vitamins => ({
    type: FETCH_VITAMINS_SUCCESS,
    payload: vitamins
  });
```

If I do: "return { vitamin: state.vitamin, }" instead of "return { vitamin: state, }", I get back "TypeError: Cannot read property 'vitamin' of undefined". But that's what I called vitaminReducer in my combineReducers() function at the bottom of reducers.js, so I thought that was the right way to do it.

Comment: you call `mapStateToProps()` but it expects a state as an argument... It's a mapping function, you should just pass it to `connect` not call it by yourself.

Comment: @TomaszMularczyk  I'm a little confused. I have to pass something in there, don't I? I want to pass state so I can map over my "vitamins" array through another function. What do you mean by "just pass it to `connect` not call it by yourself?

Comment: @bigjohnjr You dont need to call mapStateToProps because its a part of connect's internal mechanisms. It seems you havent grasp entirely the redux and redux react principles, head over egghead.io theres a nice tutorial by Abramov himself. It seems you are mixing vanilla JS and ES6 syntax without real purposes, so I strongly recommend you to follow a JS course like "You dont know JS". When you call console.log('the state is', mapStateToProps());, you're basically calling mapStateToProps with an undefined argument: state is undefined inside, giving you the TypeError.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? map state to props is to be used (only) by `connect`, that's how `redux-thunk` sets the component's properties according to the `store`. So, what's your goal here?

Comment: @Barazu my goal is just to return the vitamins array to Vitamins.js, and use my `renderData()` function to map over each vitamin and return their names in an `select` dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your input! I was able to get it working.

I ditched the mapStateToProps() and instead did this

(Vitamins.js)

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchVitamins();
  }

  renderData() {
   const { vitamins } = this.props.vitamins;
    return vitamins.map((micro, index) => {
      return (
        <option value={micro.value} key={index}>{micro.name}</option>
      )
    })
  }

  export default connect(
   state => ({
     vitamins: state.vitamins
   }),
   {
    fetchVitamins
   },
   )(Vitamins);
```

I set the dispatch action inside of the fetchVitamins() function

(actions.js)

```
  export function fetchVitamins() {
   return dispatch => {
      return fetch("/users")
       .then(handleErrors)
       .then(res => res.json())
       .then(micros => {
         dispatch({
           type: "RECEIVE_VITAMINS",
           payload: micros.vitamins
         });
        }
     )};
   };

   export const RECEIVE_VITAMINS = 'RECEIVE_VITAMINS';
```

In reducers I set the initialState to the vitamins array, and passed the new state of micros.vitamins from my RECEIVE_VITAMINS action

(reducers.js)

```
  const initialState = {
    vitamins: [],
  }

 function vitaminReducer(state = initialState, action) {
   switch(action.type) {
     case RECEIVE_VITAMINS:
      return {
        ...state,
        vitamins: action.payload
      };
  default:
     return state;
  }
}


const reducers = combineReducers({
   vitamins: vitaminReducer,
});
```

Thanks everyone for your help! Let me know if you have any other suggestions :D